# Use environment variable in word within command

Tags: bash, shell, unix, environment-variables

I want to programmatically create this output:

```
s1a
s2a
s3a
s4a
s5a
```

where I may go to any number of rows, not just 5. My approach is to use a for loop, referencing an environment variable iterator:

```
$ for i in $(seq 1 5); do echo s$ia ; done
s
s
s
s
s
```

How can I differentiate between the environment variable `$i` and the character `a`? I want to avoided referencing some `$ia` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- There are no *environment* variables in your code, only *shell* variables.

  - Shell variables may *also* be environment variables (*exported* variables such as `$PATH` that are visible to all child processes, whether they're shells or not), but that's not the case here.
- Shell variable names must be *disambiguated* from adjacent characters that could be part of a syntactically legal variable name by enclosing them in `{...}` - `${i}`, in your case.
- Unless you specifically want shell-variable references (possibly embedded in unquoted tokens) subjected to [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html), notably word-splitting and globbing, *double-quote* them - `"s${i}a"` in your case.
- Use an [arithmetic, C-style loop](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/c_for) to create a memory-efficient loop with a variable number of iterations.

To put it all together:

```
$ n=5; for (( i = 1; i <= n; ++i )); do echo "s${i}a"; done
s1a
s2a
s3a
s4a
s5a
```

Answer (score 4):

Variable names are greedy, meaning they'll use as much of the text as possible to form a variable name. Hence `s$ia` is the literal `s` followed by the variable `$ia`.

You need to use braces to make it non-greedy:

```
echo s${i}a
```

This means the literal `s` the variable `$i` and the literal `a`:

```
pax> for i in $(seq 1 5) ; do echo s${i}a ; done
s1a
s2a
s3a
s4a
s5a
```

---

And keep in mind, modern `bash` versions can generate those sequences *without* resorting to the external `seq`:

```
for i in {1..5} ; do ...
```

Comment: Is it worth pointing out that `i` is probably not an environment variable; it is just a shell variable.

Comment: @Jonathan, good point. I tend to often (erroneously) conflate them because even shell variables exist in the "environment" (common-English rather than `bash`-literal definition) of the shell. Since the behaviour here is independent of whether it's a shell or environment variable, I've removed the distinction. In future, I'll be more careful.

Answer (score 1):

bash brace expansion can handle that without loops or variables

```
$ echo s{1..5}a | tr ' ' '\n'
```